# Load testing using Jmeter

Tags: laravel, jmeter, jwt

I have the following scenario:

1. Users are authenticated through `JWT` in a `Laravel` API.
2. On successful login, the users can navigate to a survey form, where they can answer to a set of questions (multi-selects, selects, radio buttons etc).
3. A logged in admin can view the answers of the user in real-time (`Web-sockets` are used here), being plotted in charts. For example let's say a question is "What's your gender?", a pie chart is shown with 10% male and 90% female.

I'd like to simulate 100 users answering some predefined questions and see the response being plotted in different charts in real-time. 
I thought of using `Jmeter` for load testing. But don't know the steps to login those 100 users and simulate answering the questions.

I want to test the response time and just visually see the answers being plotted in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

1. For authenticating via JWT you need to extract the token from the first response using [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and make sure the JWT Token value is being added to the following requests via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). Check out [Testing Microservices with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-microservices-with-jmeter) article for more details if needed.
2. I believe you can record all these survey steps using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) and build the test flow out of the resulting [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers
3. You can use i.e. [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers) to simulate admin actions. Most probably you will not see "charts" themselves, however you will be able to observe raw data and use [Assertions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) to check its integrity